# C Coding: Create Char Array, Print, Reorganize, and Print Again

Tags: c, arrays, random, char

I would like to create a char array, print it, reorganize it, and then reprint it in C.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char k[4][2];
  char thing[1][1];

  strcpy(k[0] , "A");
  strcpy(k[1] , "B");
  strcpy(k[2] , "C");
  strcpy(k[3] , "D");

  printf("\nThe original order is: \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {     // fill
      printf("%s,", k[i]);
  }

  printf("\nThe reordering is: \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {    // reorder
    strcpy(thing[0], k[i]);
    j = (int)(i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (5 - i)) );

    strcpy(k[i], k[j]);
    strcpy(k[j], thing[0]);
    printf("%s,", k[i]);  // print
  }

  return(0);

}
```

Here's my Terminal Output.  There are no warnings, just the abort.

```
mac% clang thing.c -o thing
mac% ./thing

The original order is: 
A,B,C,D,
The reordering is: 
zsh: abort      ./thing
```

Comment: `char k[4][1];` -> `char k[4][2];`, there is one `null` terminator for every string.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the errors/warnings you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: Just edited to be clearer Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's the solution I came up with:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char k[4] = "ABCD";
  char thing[1] = "O";

  printf("\nThe original order is: \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {     // fill
      printf("%c,", k[i]);
  }

  printf("\nThe reordering is: \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {    // reorder
    thing[0]= k[i];
    j = (int)(i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (4 - i)) );

    k[i]= k[j];
    k[j]= thing[0];
    printf("%c,", k[i]);  // print
  }

  return(0);

}
```

And the output is

```
The original order is: 
A,B,C,D,
The reordering is: 
A,B,D,C,%
```